Why doesn't ML suffer from curse of dimensionality?
Disclaimer: I asked this question on Data Science Stack Exchange 3 days ago, and got no response so far. Maybe it is not the right site. I am hoping for more positive engagement here.
This is a question that has puzzled me for a long time. I am a trained statistician and I know that certain things cannot be done in high dimensions (or at least you won't get what you want, you may get something else though).
There's this notion of curse of dimensionality. Density estimation, for example, is notoriously slow in high dimensions as the rate of convergence of kernel density estimate is $^{−2/(2+)}$
. Clearly as →∞
, this rate basically behaves like a constant, and thus density estimation in high dimensions is essentially impossible. But we routinely see diffusion models and other methods being used in high dimensions. I am not really talking about theory here; rather they are used in Stable Diffusion, Dall-E, etc. which give good results!
Then there is the notion of separability in high dimensional classification. Logistic regression is routinely used as the top layer on many neural nets. As the dimensionality of the data grows, the classes become more and more separate. So, classification is almost trivial in high dimensions. But this also implies the fact that the logistic MLE does not exist because there can be infinitely many classifiers. So, we get a classifier, but do we get what we want?
There is a seeming disparity between what traditional knowledge offers and what ML has achieved. My question is about this disparity. What did traditional theoreticians miss? There are obvious pitfalls but somehow ML does not seem to get entrapped in them. Are we getting something else than what we really want, but because the end product "looks" good, we think that is what we wanted all this time?
Does anyone know what could be some potential reasons?

I suspect that when LR is used as the output layer of a DNN it is being used with regularisation, which makes it more robust to overfitting, but this is just the same as ridge regression and the norm of the primal parameters in the SVM training criterion.  ML is only resistant to the CoD when steps are taken to make it robust, but they can also be applied to traditional statistical methods.  "Benign overtfitting" is a bit more intruging!  The distinction between stats and ML is somewhat specious IMHO.

You're absolutely correct about the curse of dimensionality in traditional density estimation which seems impossible to estimate in very high dimensions like images. However, modern deep learning models like diffusion models and GANs don't attempt to estimate the full joint density of the data. Instead, they often work with lower-dimensional manifolds within the high-dimensional space to sidestep your concern and there's a manifold hypothesis to support the theoretical validity here.

The manifold hypothesis posits that many high-dimensional data sets that occur in the real world actually lie along low-dimensional latent manifolds inside that high-dimensional space...  It is suggested that this principle underpins the effectiveness of machine learning algorithms in describing high-dimensional data sets by considering a few common features.

Then your observation about separability in high-dimensional classification is spot-on which means that if we get a classifier that performs well on the training data it may not generalize well to unseen data. In practice DL models employ many regularization techniques, especially for neural networks such as Dropout, BatchNorm, and the common SGD with mini-batch optimization has some implicit regularization effect as well, all of these help mitigate this issue in practice.
Finally traditional statistical theory often focuses on asymptotic properties and worst-case scenarios such as PAC learning, yet modern ML stories suggest a few things that weren't fully appreciated before such as the importance of inductive biases (CNN, Transformer, etc) and representation learning to reduce the effective dimensionality of a problem. We're not necessarily getting something entirely different from what we want, but we are often trading off certain desirable properties like interpretability or provable guarantees for empirical performance.

Great answer, thanks! Do you know if the manifold hypothesis is testable?

@LandonCarter empirically your mentioned ML's practical good results have already verified the hypothesis in many cases, of course it may also be falsified statistically in some other cases especially if we restrict total data dimensions. Neuroscience has some related efficient coding hypothesis to be testable or falsifiable in the sense that both of them are really about data compression. On the theory side there's information geometry of statistical manifold embedding theory which finds the Fisher information metric doesn't describe the full geometry of space but only its conformal geometry.

@cinch isn't this a bit circular? A: "Why does ML work in high dimensions?" B: "Why, the manifold hypothesis!" A: "And how do we know the manifold hypothesis is right?" B: "Because ML works in high dimensions!"

@JohnMadden not necessarily. ML is more like inductive science rather than deductive math. Hypothesis is more like scientific laws such as Newton's law rather than a math conjecture waiting to be proved. Why Newton's law is right? Of course because it works empirically. OTOH information geometry's conformal property I mentioned above might give more insight, in the same way as general relativity's spacetime curvature gave more insight for Newton's universal gravity law which is actually false.

@cinch: Semantics maybe, but doesn't the good results from ML validate the hypothesis, rather than verify it? Meaning, it shows that the hypothesis is sensible and applicable, but doesn't say whether it's true or not. Making this distinction might help with the seeming circularity of the argument.

@AkselA here validating and verifying are colloquially synonymous for me without statistical sense of model validating, some like falsifying scientific theories instead of verifying or validating since all models/hypothesis are wrong and wait to be falsified, including the celebrated general relativity (GR), and thus usually for scientific theories or hypothesis we don't assert true or false, only yet to be falsified like GR.

@LandonCarter the fact that the data lives in a low dimensional manifold is trivially true: you can force a line going through all your points. You can also see that many complex data types can be compressed into low dimensional spaces using autoencoders; and they can be turned into smooth manifolds using VAE.
Now, is that what makes ML work in practice? I can't think of any experiment.

@Davidmh: not quite; if you have two points with the exact same predictor values but different $y$ values, no line or manifold will go through both points. I would rather say that training a model is a question of finding the "best" manifold $M$ in terms of the distance of points from $M$ and the "regularity" of $M$, compare different notions on curvature etc. from differential geometry. And yes, "regularity" is supposed to suggest "regularization", which is nothing else than constraining $M$. And no, I would not know how to test such a hypothesis, either.

@Davidmh the manifold hypothesis says not that a particular finite sample, such as the training dataset, lies on a low-dimensional manifold. That would be trivially true, as you say. What it says is that there is a manifold on which any arbitrary sample lives, or indeed the entire (inaccessible) infinite population. I'd say the way to test that is indeed pretty much what ML people do every day: train a model until you get good performance on the training set (-> hypothesis for where the manifold lies), then evaluate the same model on a previously unseen test set.

ML has all the problems of statistical models and more with respect to the curse of dimensionality.  Think of it this way.  A standard statistical model assumes additivity, and if it assumes assumes linearity (not a good idea) has only $p$ parameters besides intercepts to estimate for $p$ predictors/features.  ML allows for all possible 2-way interactions and more, so until shrinkage kicks in will have $> p + p(p-1)/2$ parameters.  This is highly related to a key finding from this paper which found that when binary logistic regression needs 20 times as many events as parameters to not overfit, ML may require 200 events per candidate features.

That's interesting! This makes sense intuitively. But arguably the modern benefits have been delivered - somehow - by ML methods going beyond CoD. Traditional methods have either not been tried hard or failed. not sure what went wrong then.

Only in the past 3 or so years have fair comparisons been made between statistical models and ML and the results are far less impressive for ML than previously believed.   ML tends to offer significant gains when dimensionality is high and the signal:noise ratio is very high, as in image or sound recognition.  Related to this: When S:N is high (true $R^2$ is high) it is much harder to overfit.

@FrankHarrell That S:N remark is very interesting. Do you happen to have any references on this topic at hand that you could point to? (I'm asking because I had a question about noise models in ML a long time ago for which this might be part of the answer.)

No, I just elaborate on some of this in https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg .  But if you look at all the greatest successes of ML the vast majority have been in very high S:N situations.  For example with chess or Go S:N = $\infty$.

To be clear, @LandonCarter, there is nothing wrong with working on problems with super-high signal-to-noise ratios. I used speech-recognition software in the car last night to tell Spotify what music to play, and that would not exist if people didn't study high SNR settings. However, do recognize that not all problems have such high signal-to-noise ratios.

@FrankHarrell in a way the high SNR is achieved through massive data. The interesting point here is that the models are also huge (perhaps artificially huge because of the intrinsic low dimensionality as posited by manifold hypothesis).

@FrankHarrell I hear your point about non-impressiveness of ML models in lower SNR regimes, but I do not buy that. The (very, in my view) important issue here is that the most capable models required tons of training, tons of compute and hence tons of money. Somebody had to invest money for those problems to be solved. For low SNR problems, who will invest? As a result we will be stuck with poor models. In my view this is not a fair comparison.

No I'm speaking about SNR that is sample size independent (although increasing N will make all methods be more reliable).  And I'm afraid I don't grasp your last point.

I am saying that I think low SNR problems might be of lower interest from he point of view of investment by big companies (they are not as flashy as protein folding or chess for example). The most capable models (with which we should be comparing our traditional methods) are built by investments from big companies. Such investment is missing in many problem areas, and so as of now, we'll have to accept it as hypothetical that DL methods wouldn't perform well in low SNR regimes. Maybe they would, if someone employs a bunch of GPUs and hires smart people - aka, spends money!

But I am very intrigued by your comment that recently, comparisons have been made to show that DL works in high SNR regimes. I do believe (shakily) in this, and would love to have some references. Are you aware of any such comparison? I'd be really glad, but no worries if you don't - I'll try to look for them.

@LandonCarter: I think that "in a way the high SNR is achieved through massive data" reflects a misunderstanding. The SNR is independent of sample size. If you train your model on a trillion flips of a fair coin, you will still not be able to predict better than "50% chance of heads". Far too many people think that massive amounts of data + massive models = accuracy on a par with digit recognition. That is simply not the way noise works. (I forecast retail sales. There is a limit to forecastability. Not all my customers understand that.)

I've posted a question that explicitly asks about how signal-to-noise ratio interacts with predictive modeling. @StephanKolassa

@StephanKolassa The SNR you are thinking of is different from the SNR I am thinking of. Actually I don't think SNR has a proper definition: people use that word to mean different things in different settings. In your example, you are talking about "predictive SNR" namely can I predict the next coin flip outcome. I agree that's impossible. But I am thinking of "estimation SNR", which means, can I estimate the bias of the coin? This certainly can be improved with higher sample size. These "predictive SNR" and "estimation SNR" are of course not meaningful terms, I just wanted to illustrate.

I think SNR traditionally has to mainly to do with how clearly one can separate signals from noise.  To me $R^2$ is as good a summary of that as I've seen.  In this context $R^2$ is unknown but can be estimated, and refers to a hypothetical model that uses all the data to predict the response.

"But if you look at all the greatest successes of ML the vast majority have been in very high S:N situations" there are lots of very successful uses of ML in low signal to noise, e.g. image recognition, speech recognition, autonomous vehicles etc.  The real difference between statistics and ML models seems to be ML tends to have a broader hypothesis class.  It isn't surprising it needs more data, but then again it is more powerful.  Personally I don't see a real distinction between ML and stats - it is all stats with varying degrees of computational expense.

@DikranMarsupial Wouldn't those be situations where humans can perform the task quite well? I can recognize digits. I can understand spoken English. I can drive a car. My impression is that the comments here are pointing to ML success in situations that we know are solvable, just for tasks that we want computers to do instead of humans.

@Dave knowing something is solvable does not mean it has a high signal to noise ratio.  I can drive a car not because the sensory inputs have high signal to noise (e.g. driving on a rainy night), but because I have a big brain (compared to ML) to understand it.  All problems are solvable to some degree, the error/approximation is continuous not boolean.  ML does suffer from the curse of dimensionality just like stats, and the solutions are the same (e.g. regularisation).  I don't buy into a clear demarcation between stats and ML, it is largely a difference of computational budget/complexity.

I had a quick look at the study mentioned in the answer, and I would have recommended rejection if I were a reviewer as it doesn't explain how the hyper-parameters of the SVM were tuned and (while I don't know R) it doesn't look to me that they were tuned, which is a substantial problem as that is how strutural risk minimisation is implemented, so if you don't tune the hyperparameters, you are not using the SVM correctly.  Caveat lector - I only gave it a brief skim (including the additional material) so it is possible I missed something.

@DikranMarsupial the situations you are calling low S:N would be considered very high S:N when compared to biomedical problems in my area, such as estimating the risk that a woman has ovarian cancer from protein markers from her blood.

@FrankHarrell There are plenty of successful uses of SVMs in that sort of problem as well, that I have researched myself, e.g. predicting gene regulation.  There is no statistical distinction between ML and statistics, the only real difference tends to be that ML models have a larger hypothesis class., which has both advantages and disadvantages.  Do you have a response to the issue that I raised regarding the paper you cite in your answer, which seems to me to be deeply flawed?

Only that the paper could be improved, like all papers.  I don’t think the central message will change.  It’s clear that ML has a larger parameter space leading to more overfitting when the signals are dominated by additive effects.  Regarding the success of ML in situations such as the ovarian cancer diagnosis problem, the track record is not impressive.

@FrankHarrell no, if they didn't perform model selection for the SVM, the results are meaningless.  Structural Risk Minimisation is central to the SVM, so if they ignored that it is a fundamental flaw.  It isn't surprising that statistical methods applied correctly are more efficient than ML methods performed badly.  A valid comparison must use all methods according to best practice to be useful.  You can't use a single application as evidence of anything - no free lunch theorems tell us that.

BTW this could be an example of "operator bias".  People get good results from tools they know how to use.  One of the problems with stats and to a greater extent ML, there are lots of toolboxes that are used by people that don't understand how the tools work or how they should be used.  This causes more of a problem for ML as more powerful tools are easier to use badly.  But as I said, there is no real distinction between ML and statistics, just computational complexity.  The laws of statistics apply equally to both.

On the other hand, two of my colleagues spent 2 months tuning a random survival forest.  Default tuning parameters resulted in tragic overfitting.  After 2 months of playing with it they achieved a level of overfitting that was merely problematic.

Using default parameters is bad practice, so it is not surprising that it gives bad results (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06777)  Why were they so keen on Random Survival Forest?  Spending months trying to make one particular model work rather than finding the best model and then optimising that is also bad practice.  Much better to start with something simple and then try and improve on that (taking into account what you have learned/diagnosed) - sometimes you can't and that isn't a problem.  Perhaps there is something to learn from engineers after all?
